# Is there a blanket term for all variants (both nuclides and ions) of a chemical element?

Tags: ions, terminology, elements, isotope

I'm hoping to catalogue the various nuclides and oxidation states of an element but can't find a single term that describes them all, save for "chemical element variations". Is there a specific term used for this?

Comment: I don't think so. For what?

Comment: Why would there be such a term? Nuclides and oxidation states are **farther** away than just unrelated. It would be like a blanket term that covers human body parts and bank accounts.

Comment: I agree they are very different, but they are nonetheless connected by the nomenclature in use, in that both would be labelled with the base element's symbol (Na+, 24Na). If a body part and a bank account are both called "Sam" then they should be in a list of all things called "Sam". That they are fundamentally different things is beside the point in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, for example consider selenium. You can say "selenium species".

Comment: Exactly, I always counter "nitrogen species" for instance, to account for ammonium, nitrite, nitrate and all other forms.

Comment: True how about "sulfur species", maybe this could be a new game for the chemists here. We might have to each think of an element and name several forms. For sulfur, sulfide, sulfite, thiosulfate, sulfate and peroxydisulfate.

Comment: That works (and I see that confirmed here: https://goldbook.iupac.org/html/C/CT06859.html). A little ambiguous as it seems to have some overlap but seems like it's the best option there is. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Dan for adding the reference to the IUPAC gold book